# Sort a nested dict into an ordered list in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

I have the following dict:

```
d = {'d_1': {'score': 5.2, 'concept': 'a'}, 
     'd_2': {'score': 10.1, 'concept': 'e'}, 
     'd_3': {'score': 1.5, 'concept': 'c'}, 
     'd_4': {'score': 20.2, 'concept': 'd'}, 
     'd_5': {'score': 0.9, 'concept': 'b'}}
```

I want to get a sorted list, by score, like so:

```
d_sorted = [{'d_4': {'score': 20.2, 'concept': 'd'}},
            {'d_2': {'score': 10.1, 'concept': 'e'}},
            {'d_1': {'score': 5.2, 'concept': 'a'}},
            {'d_3': {'score': 1.5, 'concept': 'c'}},
            {'d_5': {'score': 0.9, 'concept': 'b'}}]
```

I tried the following, but that will sort by concept, not score:

```
d_sorted = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

How would I sort this nested dict by the score key (descending) into an ordered list in Python 2.7?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of [Sort a nested dict into an ordered list in Python 2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34787475/sort-a-nested-dict-into-an-ordered-list-in-python-2-7) because it concerns nested dicts.

Comment: dict cannot be sorted

Comment: I know, I want to get a sorted list out of my dict.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extract the value first:

```
[{k: v} for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=(lambda x: x[1]['score']), reverse=True)]
```